# Anbox sound isnt working, how do I fix it?

Tags: sound, anbox

(I am very trash at ask ubuntu because i dont know if i am posting in the wrong section, I dont even know if there are sections but sorry if i am)

So basically Ive had anbox for over a year and for some reason the sound stopped working around 5-7 months ago. I am looking for a fix online but for some reason nobody really even talks about the problem anymore, so Im not sure if its a me problem or an everyone problem.

Comment: last time i used this website was nearly 2 years ago

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and solved it. Apparently there is a problem with latest prebuilt .img file for anbox, which for some reason lacks config files for media codecs, including audio codecs.
You can get the necessary config files [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anbox/anbox/master/android/media/media_codecs.xml)
They must be accessible to Android in the /system/etc directory of the image. To achieve it, you can either use rootfs overlay as described [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=982267)
or made another image. For the latter, unpack the original image using `unsquash android.img` (this will unpack it into a file tree with root directory squashfs-root) then put the config files into `squashfs-root/system/etc` and pack image by command `mksquashfs squashfs-root android.img -comp xz` Naturally, you should then put the new images to where anbox expects it and restart the system service anbox-container-manager and the user service anbox-session-manager.